# IntegrityError: null value in column "is_approved" violates not-null constraint

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Firstly , i was told to add a field to my model to help the admin approve, disapprove or pend products before they can be seen on the website. So, i added

```
class Product(models.Model):
  ...there are some fields here...
  is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

to my product model, did the routine migrations, edited the serializer, views,urls,tested it and pushed to microsoft azure.

2nd, i had another instruction to change the same field to *approval_status*

```
STATUS = [
    ('0', 'Pending Approval'),
    ('1', 'Approved'),
    ('2', 'Rejected')
] 

class Product(models.Model):
  ...there are some filed here...
     approval_status = models.CharField(
        choices=STATUS,
        default='0',
        max_length=2
    )
```

after deploying, i have this error

> IntegrityError at /marketplace/create_product/
> null value in column "is_approved" violates not-null constraint
> DETAIL:  Failing row contains (620, , , 2.00, FTF, 0, PR, , , , 113, 2021-05-03 11:38:28.57937+00, null, 0).*

i am suspecting the server database couldn't replace the **is_approved** field with **approval_status**, but rather included it, and hence trying to return that value.
i have am expecting 13 fields but 14 are been returned
Kindly help me with ideas to solve the error.

my model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        'Accounts.BusinessInfo',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=True,
    )
    description = models.TextField(
        blank=True
    )
    price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=2
    )
    category = models.CharField(
        choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES,
        default='FTF',
        max_length=10
    )
    discount = models.IntegerField(
        default=0
    )
    product_type = models.CharField(
        choices=PRODUCT_TYPE,
        default='PR',
        max_length=2
    )
    image_1 = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='products',
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    image_2 = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='products',
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    image_3 = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='products',
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True
    )
    approval_status = models.CharField(
        choices=STATUS,
        default='0',
        max_length=2
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.owner.user.is_organization:
            raise ValueError('You have to be an organization to create a product')
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

my serializer

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = BusinessInfoSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'id', 'owner', 'name', 'description', 'price', 'category', 'discount', 'product_type',
            'image_1', 'image_2', 'image_3', 'timestamp',  'approval_status'
        ]

        extra_kwargs = {
            'id': {'required': False, 'read_only': True},
            'owner': {'required': False},
        }
```

my views

```
class CreateProduct(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects
    model = Product
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_classes = (JWTAuthentication,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        product_owner = BusinessInfo.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        serializer.save(owner=product_owner)
```

my url

```
    path(
        'create_product/',
        CreateProduct.as_view(),
        name='CreateProduct'
    ),
```

0001_initial.py

```
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Product',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)),
                ('description', models.TextField(blank=True)),
                ('price', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)),
                ('category', models.CharField(choices=[('FTF', 'Fashion, Textiles and Fabrics'), ('JGP', 'Jewellery, Gifts and Parcels'), ('SSF', 'Shoes, Sandals and Footwears'), ('AT', 'Automobile and Transport'), ('BOS', 'Books and Office Supplies'), ('LFD', 'Lights, Furniture and Decor'), ('BeL', 'Beauty and Lifestyle'), ('BaL', 'Bags and Luggage'), ('EGG', 'Electronics, Gadgets and Garden Equipment'), ('TBP', 'Toiletries / Baby Products'), ('PTC', 'Phones, Tablets and Computers'), ('GrP', 'Groceries and Provisions'), ('SE', 'services'), ('ITM', 'Industrial Tools and Machinery'), ('REP', 'Real Estates and Properties'), ('HeP', 'Health and Pharmaceuticals'), ('PlP', 'Plastics and Rubbers'), ('HE', 'Hardware Equipment'), ('MI', 'Musical Instruments'), ('BCM', 'Building and Construction Materials'), ('SFE', 'Safety Equipment'), ('FDS', 'Food, Drinks and Snacks'), ('UGK', 'Utensils, Glassware and Kitchenware'), ('PC', 'Paints and Chemicals')], default='FTF', max_length=10)),
                ('discount', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
                ('product_type', models.CharField(choices=[('PR', 'product'), ('SE', 'services')], default='PR', max_length=2)),
                ('image_1', models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='products')),
                ('image_2', models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='products')),
                ('image_3', models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='products')),
                ('timestamp', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)),
                ('owner', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='Accounts.businessinfo')),
            ],
        ),
```

0002_product_approval_status.py

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('Marketplace', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='product',
            name='approval_status',
            field=models.CharField(choices=[('0', 'Pending Approval'), ('1', 'Approved'), ('2', 'Rejected')],
                                   default='0', max_length=2),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: This data might be from the last migrations, can you delete the previous database (or just for this model) and test it again? and I suggest not deploying before testing, because you can debug easier

Comment: Can you show the content of your migration files?

Answer (score 0):

so I solved this error by manually going to the production server on azure to look for the `is_approved` field and deleting it because didn't need it anymore. I was surprised the `migrations query` could do that for me but I know there is a way to do that which I haven't yet come across.